# Graceful Shutdown Server Socket in Linux

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I want to be able to stop listening on a server socket in linux and ensure that all connections that are open from a client's point of view are correctly handled and not abruptly closed (ie: receive ECONNRESET).

ie:

```
sock = create_socket();
listen(sock, non_zero_backlog);
graceful_close(sock);
```

if thought calling close() and handling already accept'd sockets would be enough but there can be connections that are open in the kernel backlog which will be abruptly closed if you call close() on the server socket.

Comment: You might be able to do it with [`shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown). I haven't tested it though so I don't know if it will work.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. Have a look at the tail end of the discussion here: http://fixunix.com/networking/535700-disonnecting-tcp-listening-socket.html

Comment: @drscroogemcduck please define what you mean by "correctly". Getting an RST for a half-open TCP connection *is* correct, by RFC.

Comment: Why do you think the client receiving ECONNRESET is not graceful? Can you provide more background on the problem?

Comment: listen() tells the kernel to start accepting tcp connections on that socket, and then you retrieve them with accept(). Sounds like you want to somehow 'stopListening()' (ie have the kernel stop accept incoming connections) and then call accept() to empty the backlog. At this point you could close the server socket without having any "connections that are open in the kernel backlog which will be abruptly closed". As to how you would go about stopping listening, I've no idea. Maybe set the kernel-layer buffer size for incoming connections to zero somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only working way to do that (that I have found) is to:

1. prevent `accept()` from adding more clients
2. have a list of the open sockets somewhere and to wait until they are all properly closed which means:

   - using `shutdown()` to tell the client that you will no longer work on that socket
   - call `read()` for a while to make sure that all the client has sent in 
     the meantime has been pulled
   - then using `close()` to free each *client* socket.
3. THEN, you can safely `close()` the listening socket.

You can (and should) use a timeout to make sure that idle connections will not last forever.

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR seems to be a decent solution on local sockets, its probably still for the best to cleanly exit but that might not be possibly in all situations.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a limitation of the TCP socket API. You can look at `ECONNRESET` as the socket version of `EOF` or, you can implement a higher level protocol over TCP which informs the client of an impending disconnection.

However, if you attempt the latter alternative, be aware of the intractable [Two Armies Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) which makes graceful shutdown impossible in the general case; this is part of the motivation for the TCP connection reset mechanism as it stands. Even if you could write `graceful_close()` in a way that worked most of the time, you'd probably still have to deal with `ECONNRESET` unless the server process can wait forever to receive a `graceful_close_ack` from the client.