# Is it safe to read from pipe OR socketpair with one end closed till reaching EOF?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, socketpair

Consider the following **EXAMPLE** code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main()
{
    int sv[ 2 ] = { 0 };
    socketpair( AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0, sv );

    for( unsigned ii = 0; ii < 5; ++ii )
    {
        int* msg = new int( 123 );
        if( -1 == send( sv[ 0 ], &msg, sizeof(int*), MSG_NOSIGNAL ) )
        {
            delete msg;
        }
    }

    close( sv[0] );
    sleep( 1 );

    int* msg = 0;
    int r;
    while( ( r = read( sv[ 1 ], &msg, sizeof(int*) ) ) > 0 )
    {
        delete msg;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>Obviously, the code works fine, but it doesn't mean it's not UB.</sub>

Couldn't find anything in the man pages, which guarantees, that when `sv[ 0 ]` is closed, the `read` will still be able to read everything from `sv[ 1 ]`, sent by the `send`.

---

Maybe the question could be asked like this - *as `read` returns `0` for `EOF` and as the `socketpair` is `SOCK_STREAM`, I expect the `EOF` will be "hit" once everything is read from the socket and the other side is closed. Is this correct?*

Comment: What is meaning of `::read` and others in C?

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild - others? This is a small example for network programming - write to and read from sockets. And, as the tags show, this is platform-specific (for Linux in this case).

Comment: TIL, in Linux C is C++

Comment: I still didn't understand!!! What is `::`(scope resolution operator) doing on `C` language??

Comment: I hope @TRKemp is trying to make a joke, but that comment is confusing...

Comment: @R.. Yes, it was a joke. I didn't think the fact that @KirilKirov was working on Linux would make C magically understand `::`.

Comment: A socket pair is not a pipe. They're two different things.

Comment: @TRKemp - I work on Linux, using C++, but this is completely valid C code, only if you remove the scope resolution operator, isn't it? I'll remove it, if it matters that much. The question is completely valid for both languages.

Comment: @duskwuff - you're right, I know. But I guess the situation is similar with `pipe` or `pipe2`. The code shows an example only with `socketpair`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it can work, but smells UB.

The correct way is the *graceful shutdown* :

- `shutdown(s, 1)` or (better `shutdown(s, SHUT_WR)`)
- read until eof on input
- only then call close.

(References : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, [Graceful Shutdown Server Socket in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681531/graceful-shutdown-server-socket-in-linux))

Edit  :

After reading R.. comment, I wondered if I was not a little confused, did some tests and read documentation again. And ... I now think what I said is true for general socket usage (include AF_INET sockets), but not for the special AF_INET socketpair.

My test was put a little more stress on the system, since I send 8 packets of 1024 bytes on a FreeBSD 9 system. I stopped there because sending more would have blocked. And after the close on sv[0] I could successfully read my 8 packets.

So it works on different kernels, but could not find a valid reference for it except that AF_UNIX sockets do not support OOB data.

I could also confirm that using shutdown, works fine.

Conclusion : 
As far as I am concerned, I would stick to graceful shutdown for closing a socket, but mostly because I do not want to think about the underlying protocol.

Hope somebody else with more knowledge could give a piece of reference documentation

Comment: No, close is perfectly correct here. It would only be dangerous if you closed the end you're reading from, not the other end. In general the other end is in a different process or even on a different host outside your control and it will close, so if that caused UB in your program, you'd be in big trouble with no solution.

Comment: @R.. - that's exactly what I think, but couldn't find anything, that proofs it. Anyway, can you write that in an answer?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - yes, I thought about `shutdown` and I also thought it would be better to use it instead of `close`. But, BUT, as @R.. points out, the other side of the "channel" could be under the control of completely different system, on completely different host and if reading from socket connection, which is closed on the other side, causes UB, then .. yeah, you get my point, and @R..'s.

Comment: I appriciate the tests and the answer, thanks for the effort :)