# read() from pipe guaranteed to provide all atomically written data before EOF?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm using a simple `fork()` parent-child example to have the child generate some data, and `write()` it for the parent. The child will atomically write less than `64kib` (65536 bytes) of data atomically to the pipe.

The parent reads from the pipe, and when it receives `EOF` (ie: assuming that the remote side has been closed), it carries on with some processing logic and closes at its own convenience, and doesn't care how long it takes the child to terminate.

Is the parent guaranteed to be able to read all of the client data that was sent before `EOF` is encountered, or does any potential OS-level logic kick in to trigger the `EOF` early before all of the data is read?

[I have found a very similar question on SO, but it didn't receive an authoritative/cited answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446975/is-it-safe-to-read-from-pipe-or-socketpair-with-one-end-closed-till-reaching-eof)

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is misphrased. "Atomically" has nothing to do with it. Since it is more than 512 bytes, it is *not* guaranteed to be atomic, but that doesn't *matter* for your use case.

Comment: In POSIX-compliant systems, write/read operations are guaranteed to be *atomic* (i.e., data from one operation is not interleaved with data from another operation) if the number of bytes is at most PIPE_BUF. POSIX guarantees PIPE_BUF to be *at least* 512 bytes -- actual implementation varies. (Ninja edit: on Linux it used to be 4096 bytes; so operations of at most 4096 bytes were guaranteed to be atomic; if you had multiple writers writing more than that, data may interleave.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the parent will be able to read all the data. To put your mind at ease, try the following in a shell:

```
echo test | (sleep 1; cat)
```

The echo command is done immediately; the other side of the pipe will wait one second and then tries to read from it. This just works.

The child can also write more than 64 kiB without problems, as long as the parent will keep on reading in a loop, although then it won't be atomic any longer.

Comment: Note that the child will be blocked until the parent reads some of the data if the total written is more than 64 KiB or if the current write can't be kept atomic until some data is read by the parent.